# using and/or in JasperReport expression

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

i want to use and/or in JasperReport expression
i tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
($P{pId} == $F{id1}) or
($P{pId} == $F{id2} and F{return}=true)
? "good" : "bad"
```

but i am getting following exception:

```
Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@1c9f37d  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, calculator_report1_1318247835062_860381: 191: unexpected token: or @ line 191, column 144. 1 error      at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:88)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:188)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:131)     at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:509)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

any ideas why i am getting this exception and how to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`and` and `or` are not valid Java operators. JasperReports uses Java expressions. And since all Jasper parameters and fields are objects, I doubt you want to compare them with `==`. Use equals instead.

```
($P{pId}.equals($F{id1}) ||
 ($P{pId}.equals($F{id2}) && F{return}.booleanValue()))
? "good" : "bad"
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine, and i had to put all the conditions before the question mark between one bracket (conditions) ? "true": "false"